# Fatal error: Call to undefined function register_new_user()

Tags: php, functions, user-registration, wp-create-user

Have a wordpress theme with custom registration. Registration works on the registration page. If I take the form and place it on another page , eg. Homepage.. it gives me this error.

Here is the code for my form

```
// Form

<div class="container">

          <?php if(edd_get_errors()){?>
           <div class="error flash">
                  <p><?php __( 'Please review the following issues that occurred', 'forest' ); ?></p>
                  <ul>
                      <?php forest_print_errors();?>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <?php } else if(isset($_GET['success']) && $_GET['success'] == "ok") {?>
                   <div class="success flash">
                          <p><?php echo __( 'Thank you, You will receive your new password via email.  For security, please change this upon login', 'forest' ); ?></p>
                        </div>
                <?php }?>
                <div class="content-s">
                     <div class="content-box">
                        <?php if (get_option('users_can_register')){ ?>

                                        <form id=""  class="horizontal-form" action="" method="post">
                                          <fieldset>

                                                        <div class="input-group">
                                                                <label for="user_login"><?php echo __( 'Username', 'forest' ); ?>:</label>
                                                                <div class="inputs">
                                                                  <input name="user_login" id="user_login" class="required" type="text" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['user_login']) ? esc_attr(stripslashes($_POST['user_login'])):''; ?>"/>
                                                                </div>
                                                        </div>

                                                        <div class="input-group">
                                                                <label for="user_email"><?php echo __( 'E-mail Addy', 'forest' ); ?>:</label>
                                                                <div class="inputs">
                                                                  <input name="user_email" id="user_email" class="required" type="text" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['user_email']) ? esc_attr(stripslashes($_POST['user_email'])):''; ?>"/>
                                                                </div>
                                                        </div>

                                                        <div class="input-group">
                                                                <div class="inputs">
                                                                 <em><?php echo __( 'The password will be e-mailed to you.', 'forest' ); ?></em>
                                                                </div>
                                                        </div>

                                                        <div class="form-submit">
                                                                 <input type="hidden" name="edd_redirect" value="<?php bloginfo('url') ?>/wp-login.php?action=register&success=ok"/>
                                                                <input type="hidden" name="edd-registre-nonce" value="<?php echo wp_create_nonce( 'edd-registre-nonce' ); ?>"/>
                                                                <input type="hidden" name="edd_action" value="user_registre"/>
                                                                <button type="submit" class="btn-icon submit"><?php echo __( 'Create Account', 'forest' ); ?></button>
                                                        </div>

                                                </fieldset>
                                    </form>

                                <?php } else {?>
                                  <h1><?php echo __('Registration is closed','forest'); ?></h1>
                                  <p><?php echo __('Sorry, you are not allowed to register by yourself on this site!','forest'); ?></p>
                                  <p><?php echo __('You must either be invited by one of our team member or request an invitation by email.','forest'); ?></p>
                                <?php }?>
                    </div>
                </div>

        </div>
```

and here is the code for the function

```
function forest_process_registre_form( $data ) {
        if ( wp_verify_nonce( $data['edd-registre-nonce'], 'edd-registre-nonce' ) ) {

                $errors = register_new_user($data['user_login'], $data['user_email']);
                if ( isset($errors) && is_array($errors) ){
                        foreach($errors as $error) {
                                if(count($error) > 0) {
                                        foreach($error as $e) {
                                                edd_set_error( 'email_incorrect', $e[0]);
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                }
                // Check for errors and redirect if none present
                $errors = edd_get_errors();
                if ( ! $errors ) {
                        $redirect = apply_filters( 'edd_login_redirect', $data['edd_redirect'], $user_ID );
                        wp_redirect( $redirect );
                        exit;
                }
        }
}
add_action( 'edd_user_registre', 'forest_process_registre_form' );
```

Full function code [here](http://pastebin.com/KtaqaP89)

Why won't register_new_user() work if the form is placed anywhere else?

Comment: Are you doing _anytning_ atypical with load there? The function is defined in `wp-includes/user.php` and should be available for any normal WP core load.

Comment: The move to `wp-includes/user.php` was _very_ recent. What version of WordPress are you using?

Comment: @s_ha_dum I am using wp version 3.6 at the moment.

Comment: @Rarst Not that I am aware of.  I know the function is deprecated.  But the registation runs fine on the page with url 'wp-login.php?action=register' its only when I take the form I have outside of that page it breaks.  I want to have a register modal in the header so a user can quickly register.  Why it doesn't register is outside baffles me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I `grep`ed a 3.6 install and got this:

```
./wp-login.php:321:function register_new_user( $user_login, $user_email ) {
./wp-login.php:550:             $errors = register_new_user($user_login, $user_email);
```

Notice the function definition is in `wp-login.php`.

If you look at [the current `wp-login.php`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-login.php), it isn't there anymore and there is a note at the top of the page, just above the code:

> Last change on this file was 25231, checked in by SergeyBiryukov, 11
>   days ago
>
> Move `check_password_reset_key()`, `reset_password()`, and
>   `register_new_user()` from `wp-login.php` to `wp-includes/user.php`, to make
>   them reusable. props beaulebens for initial patch. fixes #20279.

That migration of code has been needed for a long, long time. I am glad it was finally done. Your fix is to update WordPress.

Comment: Very interesting.  I have upgraded to 3.6.1, yet I still get th error Call to undefined function register_new_user()  This is inside a themes custom function file.  So can the function be called if its outside wp-login.php.   The fix you listed makes perfect sense why it is doing that but it still fails to process the registration.

Comment: Do you have any caching on the site?

Comment: I have cleared the cache.  However I have downloaded the latest version manually and found that 'register_new_user' still exists in wp-login.php even though it has meant to have migrated to wp-includes/user.php.  So they haven't included it in 3.6.1!  Shall I just move the code manually?  If so, am I just moving that function to user.php?

Comment: The [subversion release](http://wordpress.org/download/svn/) should have the latest patches.

Comment: Thankyou so much!  This has fixed the issue.  How you found that and resolved the issue is amazing, you rock!

Comment: I gave away the secret-- [`grep`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep)